# java concurrency: BlockingQueue based producer/consumer does not seem to work well with compound actions that needs synchronized code block?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, blockingqueue

It comes to a surprise to me when I am trying to implement some compound actions with a BlockingQueue based producer/consumer pattern, which makes me think I most likely have missed something obvious.

---

## 1. In short

I need

- my consumer to make sequence actions in form of ‘take obj from the queue + do more consumer operations on the obj’ atomic and
- My producer to make sequence actions in form of ‘offer obj onto the queue + do more producer operations on the obj’ atomic and
- The two above atomic sequences synchronized on the same obj, obviously

Without such atomicity, problem may occur, see '**PROBLEM!!**' as an example in the comment in code for the producer in the following section 2.

But I can’t simply put a synchronized block around the call to take() and its associated consumer operations as **when the queue is empty**, this consumer will be stuck there **FOREVER** since it will still possess the sync lock while it waits on the producer to fill the queue with an obj, and that sync lock possession of consumer will in turn stop the producer from entering corresponding critical region to do any 'producing'.

## 2. Specially, simplified example code are as the following:

Common code known to the producer and consumer classes:

```
Queue<QObj> nbq = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();
BlockingQueue<QObj> bq = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
List<String> idList = new LinkedList<>();
Object lockObj = idList;
int Idx = 1;

public static class QObj {
    public String id;
    public String content;

    public QObj(String id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

Main logic in producer class:

```
    public void produceBlocking() {
        QObj o = new QObj(String.valueOf(Idx), "Content_" + Idx++);
//        synchronized(lockObj) {
//        no point to include Queue.offer(...) call in a synchronized block as we
//        won't be able to use synchronized() in corresponding consumer anyway
//        for the reason described above
            bq.offer(o);
            synchronized (lockObj) {
                // PROBLEM!! by now, 'o' could have been 'consumed' already
                //  hence we shouldn't do the following operations:

                // do the associated part of compound action of 'producer'
                idList.add(o.id);
                // do some more operation as part of this compound action ...
            }
//        }
    }
```

Main logic in consumer class:

```
    public void consumeBlocking() {
        while (true) {
            try {
//                synchronized (lockObj) {
//                can't simply put synchronized() here to make the following compound action atomic
//                  - when the queue is empty, this consumer will be stuck here forever since it still possesses
//                      the lockObj, which stops the producer from entering the critical region to do any 'producing'
                    QObj o = bq.take();

                    synchronized (lockObj) {
                        // do the associated part of compound action of 'consumer'
                        idList.remove(o.id);
                        // do some more operation as part of this compound action ...
                    }
//                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

## 3. Why has this not been a common problem?

I feel that this must have been a common occurring problem when people are using BlockingQueue, and the fact that I couldn’t really locate anything addressing directly to a similar problem affirms my belief that I might have got something fundamentally wrong.

Can someone give some hint about a direct solution or point out where I thought wrong about this problem?

## 4. Alternative Ideas

I did think of a few ideas as alternatives, but I feel **none of them is addressing this issue directly and all have some drawbacks** (as highlighted '**DRAWBACK!!**' in the comments in the code)

4.1 -
Do a check using Queue.contains() before continue

```
public void produceBlockingWithCheck() {
    QObj o = new QObj(String.valueOf(Idx), "Content_" + Idx++);
    bq.offer(o);
    synchronized (lockObj) {
        // First, Check if the obj could have already been consumed

        // DRAWBACK!!: this could be very costly, e.g.
        //  when 'bq' is a LinkedBlockingQueue, and contains(...) always triggers
        //  a sequential traversal, the Queue itself can be very large

        if (bq.contains(o)) {
            // do the associated part of compound action of 'producer'
            idList.add(o.id);
            // do some more operation as part of this compound action ...
        }
    }
}
```

4.2 -
Adjust the order of ops on the producer, move the Queue.offer() call to the end

```
public void produceBlockingOrderAdjusted() {
    QObj o = new QObj(String.valueOf(Idx), "Content_" + Idx++);
    // do the associated part of compound action of 'producer', only before
    // calling BlockingQueue.offer(...)

    //  DRAWBACK!!: even this may work for this simple case, such order adjustment
    //  won't not be logically possible for all cases, will it?

    synchronized (lockObj) {
        idList.add(o.id);
        // do some more operation as part of this compound action ...
    }
    bq.offer(o);
}
```

4.3 -
Use non-blocking queues instead.

```
public void produceNonBlocking() {
    QObj o = new QObj(String.valueOf(Idx), "Content_" + Idx++);
    synchronized(lockObj) {
        nbq.offer(o);
        // do the associated part of compound action of 'producer'
        idList.add(o.id);
        // do some more operation as part of this compound action ...
    }
}

public void consumeNonBlocking() {
    while (true) {
        synchronized (lockObj) {
            // kind of doing our own blocking.
            QObj o = nbq.poll();
            if (o != null) {
                // do the associated part of compound action of 'consumer'
                idList.add(o.id);
                // do some more operation as part of this compound action ...
            }

            // DRAWBACK!!: if the 'producers' don't produce faster than the 'consumers' consuming,
            // this 'miss' could be happening too often and get costly
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why has this not been a common problem?

Multi-threading is like the old board game, "[Othello](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversi)," which was marketed with the tag line, "A minute to learn, a lifetime to master." Modern threading libraries make it easy to get started writing multi-threaded code, but it's not easy to design algorithms that use multi-threading *effectively.* Sometimes, the same design principles that underly efficient, single-threaded algorithms can be completely inappropriate to use in multi-threaded code.

An experienced designer knows that when thread A puts some object in a queue to be "consumed" by thread B, it's best to let thread A be done with that object for good. Simply taking the object out of the queue should be enough for thread B to have exclusive use of it. If you can't do that without adding complexity to your design,... Well, that's the price you pay for using multiple threads.

A multi-threaded, parallel computation that's only half as efficient as a single-threaded implementation could be still could run four times as fast if it's running on an eight core machine.

Comment: Thanks heaps Solomon! your point of 'put-and-forget' is a certainly a valid sensible point. I only wonder if the 'put-and-forget' on producer is perhaps more valid in the scenario where the producer(s) and consumer(s) are the only stakeholder of the BlockingQueue? But what if we have a 3rd who needs to remove item from the BlockingQueue? e.g. an online shopping system that allows the user to issue request to cancel order if the order has not been finalized (still in the queue) yet - then a synchronized atomic composite action around the put(), take(), remove() will likely be needed?

Comment: @coderjoe, Re, cancelling an order-in-progress. OK, so that operation cannot not have a guaranteed outcome: It's an inherent data race. I would have the requesting thread simply set a `cancellationWanted` flag in the order—a very _limited_ form of "not letting go of the object"—and then any thread in the pipeline that noticed the flag either could complete the cancellation and mark the order as `cancelled`, or else mark it as `cancellationFailed`. There's various ways that the final outcome eventually could be reported back to the human user who initiated the request...

Answer (score -1):

> I need
>
> - my consumer to make sequence actions in form of ‘take obj from the queue + do more consumer operations on the obj’ atomic and
> - My producer to make sequence actions in form of ‘offer obj onto the queue + do more producer operations on the obj’ atomic and
> - The two above atomic sequences synchronized on the same obj, obviously

You can use [`wait`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#wait())+[`notifyAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll()) for that.
Try to read [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-wait-notify):
it explains `wait+notifyAll` in details.

> But I can’t simply put a synchronized block around the call to take() and its associated consumer operations as **when the queue is empty**, this consumer will be stuck there **FOREVER** since it will still possess the sync lock while it waits on the producer to fill the queue with an obj, and that sync lock possession of consumer will in turn stop the producer from entering corresponding critical region to do any 'producing'.

`wait+notifyAll` solves this problem because a thread that is waiting inside `wait()` releases the lock (and later when `wait()` need to return the thread acquires the lock again).

Also you can look at [Condition javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html).
`Condition` is the same concept as `wait+notify` but for `Lock` interface (which is more flexible and powerful version of `synchronized`).
Again, look at the `BoundedBuffer` example in the javadocs - it seems like it could be modified to do what you want in your code.